# How to do database migration with Beego framework?

Tags: go, migration, database-migration, beego

I need to add a new field to existing table, what is the correct process to do this with Beego?

I am familiar with Django's south: first you generate the migration script with `manage.py schema_migration`, then execute the migration script `manage.py migrate`.

Beego has a command `bee generate migration` to generate migration script in `database/migrations/xxx.go`. But I don't understand how to use this generated script, it doesn't seem to be connected with anything.

And I don't see any documentation mentioning migration.

Answer (score 7):

Came across the same issue, I'm using MySql. Here is how I've done it-

Created a migration file using `bee generate`:

```
$ bee generate migration user
2016/06/26 13:36:31 [INFO] Using 'user' as migration name
2016/06/26 13:36:32 [INFO] Migration file generated: /path/to/project/database/migrations/20160626_140247_user.go
2016/06/26 13:36:32 [SUCC] generate successfully created!
```

Now the file will be generated and below is the content of the file:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/astaxie/beego/migration"
)

// DO NOT MODIFY
type User_20160626_140247 struct {
    migration.Migration
}

// DO NOT MODIFY
func init() {
    m := &User_20160626_140247{}
    m.Created = "20160626_140247"
    migration.Register("User_20160626_140247", m)
}

// Run the migrations
func (m *User_20160626_140247) Up() {
    // use m.SQL("CREATE TABLE ...") to make schema update

}

// Reverse the migrations
func (m *User_20160626_140247) Down() {
    // use m.SQL("DROP TABLE ...") to reverse schema update

}
```

Updated the `Up` and `Down` methods. In comment of these methods you can see `m.SQL` can be invoked to run raw SQL queries. Here you can use `alter` commands to update the structure.

Once you are done with the changes, you can run `bee migrate` to apply these migration. Below is the example-

```
$bee migrate -conn="username:password@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/mydb"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm having trouble with this, is there a way this migration script will work without having to actually type in any RAW SQL in the up and down functions? I didn't seem to have this issue when I was using gorm so I'm asking.

Comment: @Ritesh What if I want to run migrations in my prod server? mysql remote access is revoked. I've ssh access, though. Is there any way other than allowing mysql remote access?

Answer (score 0):

I think you also need to add in migration file beego. Then,
bee migrate -driver='mysql' -conn='root:@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/test'

Comment: Please [edit] with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are [discouraged](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187), because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Comment: Is it any way to apply migrations without entering db credentials every time?

Answer (score 0):

Example for postgres
`bee migrate -driver=postgres -conn="postgres://my_user:my_pass@my_host:my_port/my_db?sslmode=disable"`